# Remove error on "npm start" - Error: Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: typescript, express, eslint, typescript-eslint

How can I remove this error?

1. I add `"type": "module"` - nothing
2. Rename `.eslintrc.js` to `.eslintrc.json` - nothing

[image]

`.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "overrides": [
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "tic-tac-toe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "format": "eslint src/**/*.ts --fix",
    "start": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc --build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/kirillleogky/tic-tac-toe.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/kirillleogky/tic-tac-toe/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/kirillleogky/tic-tac-toe#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.45.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.45.0",
    "eslint": "^8.29.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
  },
  "include": [
    "./src",
  ],
}
```

`src/index.ts`

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  return console.log(`http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

`[ERROR] 12:16:18 Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/kiryl/Documents/tic-tac-toe/src/index.ts`

Comment: You need to set `"module": "CommonJS"` in the `"compilerOptions"` in tsconfig.json.

Comment: @GOTO0 no
`"module": "commonjs"` still doesn't work

Comment: Forgot to mention, you'll also have to remove `"type": "module"` from package.json if you set `"module": "CommonJS"`. If the error message is different, then there is probably another problem.